# Did SARS-CoV-2 originate from ‘People letting animal blood drip on their food’?

Tags: covid-19

On the 2nd March, a popular German talk show format – [*Hart aber Fair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hart_aber_fair) which translates to *Harsh but Fair* – that airs on Germany’s number one television network, the ARD, broadcast an episode concerning the spread of the novel Coronavirus strain [SARS-CoV-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2) (previously known as 2019-nCoV), the cause of the [current Covid-19 outbreak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019). Among the guests of the show was professor of medical microbiology and virology [Alexander Kekulé](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_S._Kekul%C3%A9) (link to German Wikipedia page) of the Martin-Luther-University of Halle-Wittenberg.

At about 1:42 h into the show [which can be viewed on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TECNwQBk9O4), he makes the following claim about the origin of this strain of Coronavirus:

> Menschen haben irgendwelche Tiere im Wald gefangen, ihnen bei lebendigem Leib die Kehle durchgeschnitten und das Blut dann auf ihr Essen tropfen lassen, weil das so Kultur ist.

Translated:

> People caught some random animals in the forest, cut open their neck while still alive and let the blood drip on their food, because it’s their culture.

This is quoted in a review of the show published by the [*Süddeutsche Zeitung*](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/medien/hart-aber-fair-extra-coronavirus-kritik-1.4828397) in which it is presented as unchallenged, factual and one of the many things the audience and other guests learned from Professor Kekulé that evening (paraphrased).

This is the first time I have heard this type of claim on the virus’ origin. It not only seems incredible to be but also some form of orientalism stereotype for which stronger descriptions might be applicable. I want to imagine that I would have at least heard of this alleged cultural practice before. Thus, I ask:

- Is any cultural practice as described found in central China?
- Is there any evidence that *this* chain of events led to the transmission of SARS-CoV-2 from wildlife to humans?

Comment: But SARS is not a bloodborne virus, unlike HIV and hepatitis. It is contagious/infectious so the blood practice in itself isn't relevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane "We found the presence of 2019-nCoV in anal swabs and blood as well" : https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/22221751.2020.1729071

Comment: Does he ever say what kind of animal? Conservative talk radio in the USA has been blaming bat meat (eg Ben Shapiro), which isn't exactly worthy of skepticism except for the frequent flippancy of the source.

Comment: @WeatherVane Depends on the context of the claim. If emergence (ie that the novel covid-19 mutated from some other coronavirus), then yes it's a relevant topic. If context is only infectious transmission, no, it's not particularly relevant what you do with blood when the agent is airborne.

Comment: The genome sequence of the new coronavirus is a [96% match](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2012-7) for the one found in bats and people [do eat bats in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_as_food), so it is fairly plausible that eating bats was the initial vector of infection. Anything beyond that should probably be seen as part of the literary work of the people in that talk show.

Comment: @Tgr That percentage would mean four times the genetic distance than between humans and chimpanzees (99% match). I suppose, smaller genome and more frequent mutation means that 96% match *with a virus* still means "extremely close"?

Comment: Not that I am any kind of expert (or even well-educated layperson) in this topic but a google search tells me human mutation rate is 1e-8 per site per generation, which gives a very rough estimate of 1e6 generations (ie. 20 million years) for a 1e-2 distance (of course mutations or not the only mechanism for genome change in higher-level organisms, and this estimate ends up being a little high, but within the right ballpark), and the mutation rate for coronavirus is something like 1e-3 per year, so a 4e-2 distance would take about 40 years. So depends on your definition of "extremely" I guess.

Comment: ...but closer than any other animals tested so far (and of course we only tested a few bats, so while the split between the human strain and the strain in that one specific bat happened decades ago, the human strain's predecessors might easily have spent those decades in a different group of bats).

Comment: (https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/01/mining-coronavirus-genomes-clues-outbreak-s-origins has some discussion of this topic, with a similar time estimate.)

Comment: The german quote should be translated more closely as "... , cut open their neck while still alive and __let blood drip on their food__, because it’s their culture." As you translated it, it sounds like getting the blood on the food was the aim, but I think  Alexander Kekulé meant that it occured by accident.

Comment: @Tgr Coronaviruses are RNA viruses, though--no check on copy accuracy and thus a **much** higher mutation rate.  Note, also, that a generation in the life of a virus is **far** shorter than in a human.

Comment: @LorenPechtel not sure how that relates to what I said.

Comment: @Tgr I was responding to your comment trying to estimate mutation rates by comparing it to human rates.

Comment: I wasn't estimating mutation rates, I was referencing a study that actually measured them.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Actually, from the context of the quote and the way it was presented in the digesting article, I understood getting blood on the food to be the aim. However, there is sufficient ambiguity both in the German and in your suggested English translation that I think your edit is fine. I will revert to the exact text as quoted by the *SZ* though – not to mention that the *haben* feels out of place there.

Comment: @Jan, sound good. Although the "haben" is in the original quote as seen on youtube, it seems to have been lost in die transcription of SZ.

Comment: @Tgr - would that mean the ingestion of bats spreads the disease, or the raising and housing of infected bats, which then spread via contact and airborne vectors, and not from being ingested?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That's one specific I couldn't find good info for my answer. Answering the literal question "is it possible to contract a respiratory illness from eating blood or flesh of an infected animal?" Compared to the general "exposure to the animal", which is trivially true as evidenced by the numerous proved origins of many viruses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This claim has two major points:

1. SARS-CoV-2 originated in some animal
2. A blood eating practice is the reason it jumped to humans

## SARS-CoV-2 very likely originated in some animal

It is extremely likely COVID-19 originated in some animal that has contact with humans before crossing the "species barrier". In fact, this happens so commonly, it's hardly a point of contention among any scientists.

A related virus to SARS-CoV-2 often takes the name SARS when causing human disease. It's well known that SARS originated in bats and jumped to civets first before infecting humans. Thus, it is currently believed that

> **The most likely ecological reservoirs for SARS-CoV-2 are bats**, but it is believed that the virus jumped the species barrier to humans from another intermediate animal host. This intermediate animal host could be a domestic food animal, a wild animal, or a domesticated wild animal which has not yet been identified.

- [Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19) Situation Report – 32 - WHO](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200221-sitrep-32-covid-19.pdf)

Bats specifically are implicated in the origination of at least 4 other similar illnesses. This happens often enough that bats, along with birds, are called "reservoir species", meaning, they seem to be like containers of human disease causing pathogens.

> "**Bats and birds are considered reservoir species for viruses with pandemic potential**," Bart Haagmans, a virologist at the Erasmus Medical Center in Rotterdam, Netherlands, told Business Insider.

- [Experts think bats are the source of the Wuhan coronavirus. At least 4 pandemics have originated in these animals. - Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/wuhan-coronavirus-sars-bats-animals-to-humans-2020-1)

## A blood eating practice may be the cause, via live-animal markets

This exact means of disease transfer to humans, dripping blood on food, is very specific. The overall tone of the claim's source is also condescending and a bit xenophobic. Skepticism is warranted. Further, how can anyone possibly know that so early in our study of the situation? They can't know. Who ever is saying such things is speaking too quickly and without authority or source.

What we can do is at least examine if it is possible that eating blood can result in novel infections of a respiratory illness. [Eating blood in Asia is somewhat common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_as_food#Asia), but I could not find any instances of raw blood eating *for asia* and certainly none as graphic as sprinkling it on other food like salt.

**Blaming a specific blood eating practice misses the many other ways illnesses spread from animals to humans**. The eating of blood itself may or may not be the exact cause (and it's really hard to tell without specific studies), but eating blood without someone exposing themselves to many other aspects of the animal is nearly impossible. The animal has to be trapped or hunted, kept for some time, sold to merchants, butchered, products packaged, then finally delivered to the consumer. All along the way the animal's flesh, blood, breath, saliva, feces, hair, etc. are in human contact. The inhalation or ingestion (whether intentional or not) of any of these can be the cause<sup>1</sup>.

Some suspicion has fallen on the peculiar pangolin, but regardless of the exact animal, the thrust of the claim is the eating of "strange" meats, by Western standards, is the cause. Both bats and pangolins are eaten in Wuhan. And this is not without merit, both generically speaking and for SARS-CoV-2 specifically:

> **Dozens of people infected early in the current outbreak worked in a live-animal market in the Chinese city of Wuhan**, but tests of coronavirus samples found at the market have yet to identify a source.

- [Mystery deepens over animal source of coronavirus - Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00548-w)

**This food market scenario is exactly where numerous scientists first cast suspicion, merely because of the human contact**, and secondarily if certain markets are known for mixing live animals, crowds, and exist in low regulatory environments, all of which exist in the Wuhan area. Specific practices like blood eating are tertiary concerns.

> The coronavirus spreading in China and the SARS outbreak of 2003 have two things in common: Both are from the coronavirus family and both **were likely passed from animals to humans in a wet market** [a market offering live animals].
>
> "Poorly regulated live-animal markets mixed with illegal wildlife trade offer a unique opportunity for viruses to spill over from wildlife hosts into the human population," the Wildlife Conservation Society said in a statement.

- [Experts think bats are the source of the Wuhan coronavirus. At least 4 pandemics have originated in these animals. - Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/wuhan-coronavirus-sars-bats-animals-to-humans-2020-1)

> "If one of these viruses [found in bats, etc] gets into a wildlife market where the chance of one animal infecting multiple people is much higher, that's where the risk is highest," said Peter Daszak, president of EcoHealth Alliance, in the journal The Scientist. His U.S.-based nonprofit organization has been studying the origins of viruses in China for 15 years.
>
> He suspects that the source is the Chinese horseshoe bat, a common species named for the pointy horseshoe-shaped protuberance on its nose. **China has a long tradition of eating wildlife, especially in the southern provinces of Guangdong and Guangxi**.

- [Coronavirus spread: Why blame bats?](https://www.mercurynews.com/2020/01/29/coronavirus-spread-why-point-the-finger-at-bats/)

And our ever excelling growth and delivery speeds are likely making it worse.

> With growing human populations increasingly encroaching on wildlife habitats, with unprecedented changes in land use, with wildlife and livestock transported across countries and their products around the world, and with a sharp increase in both domestic and international travel, **new disease outbreaks of pandemic scale are a near mathematical certainty**.

- [How China's "Bat Woman" Hunted Down Viruses from SARS to the New Coronavirus](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-chinas-bat-woman-hunted-down-viruses-from-sars-to-the-new-coronavirus1/)
   - Must read source

The *overall human contact* is the suspect, not usually any individual practice related to that contact. Further, to addresses the claim's condescending tone, this same contact happens with other disease reservoirs that are more palatable to the Western tongue, such as pigs and chickens, which are flu virus carriers. That this is a problem exclusively of culture rather than inherent in animal hunting and husbandry is ignorant at best. The claim's source should consider this fact the next time their neighbor puts a chicken coop 20 feet from their suburban house and offers to share the eggs.

Food safety regulations exist for a reason, and SARS-CoV-2 is only one. The only cultural aspects of this outbreak is that WHO and other international bodies should stress that countries with lax cleanliness regulations do better on that front and [support grassroots movements to that end](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/2020/01/china-bans-wildlife-trade-after-coronavirus-outbreak/).

---

Footnote

1. I even remember reading an old article about the African bush meat trade. The author followed around a local hunter, and noted that a baboon's blood dripped down the man's leg as he hauled it to market, which his shins were being thrashed by high grass and thorns, thereby exposing baboon blood to the hunter's blood.

Comment: Even in the unlikely event that the disease was passed by eating blood specifically, what Prof. Kekule claimed would still likely not be correct, since he refers to direct transfer of liquid blood from an animal being slaughtered onto food. This answer contains the correct conclusion: that Kekule's claim is baseless, offensive, and far-fetched, but maybe it could be more clearly foregrounded.

Comment: @Colin Exactly. I couldn't find anything for raw blood eating in Asia. I'm sure someone's done it before, but I very much doubt it's any kind of common practice.

Comment: Huh, a downvote. Maybe I'll see a competing answer soon.

Comment: "Eating blood in Asia is somewhat common" eating blood is almost universal in cultures with sedentary animal husbandry. It just makes sense to make use of as much of the animal as possible including its blood. It's only quite recently that blood has started to be considered distasteful in much of Europe as the price of meat has dropped (the non-native population of the Americas has pretty much always had meat in pretty good supply so it's not surprising Americans tend to have an even stronger aversion than Europeans)

Comment: Strong genetic evidence that bats are indeed the source of SARS-CoV-2: [Evolutionary origins of the SARS-CoV-2 sarbecovirus lineage responsible for the COVID-19 pandemic](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41564-020-0771-4), if I ever get around to editing that into the answer.